# DataTables warning: table id=tablepress-62 - Incorrect column count. Popped up on a random website

Tags: database, datatable, datatables, column-count, tablepress

I was browsing google on my MacBook Air M2 and clicked on a site when the message `DataTables warning: table id=tablepress-62 - Incorrect column count. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/18` popped up right when I clicked on the site. What does this message mean? Is this a virus/malware or something?

Comment: See [this official DataTables technical note](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/18) (which is where the error message directs you, anyway). It means someone did not build their DataTable with the right HTML structure. Not (in and of itself) a virus or malware - just a bug.

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow, I suspect: it's not directly about a programming problem you are facing.